# formControlName in table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a problem, In my table I want to use formControlName, but not input form. `Subtotale`  I don't post in ws because this value is empty, like in photo. How to use formControlName in this code? Can you suggest me any idea?

[image]

```
 <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
          <tr style="color:black;">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Note</th>
            <th>Subtotale</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let item of products;">
            <td>{{item.client_id}}</td>
             <td>
              <div class="input-field col s2">
                <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
             <input formControlName="notes" id="notes" type="text" lass="validate">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              {{100 * item.Quantity}}  // I should use formControlName but do not know how to use it. I do not want input. Is there any way you can solve it?
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

ts code:

```
this.addprod= new FormGroup({
  'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  'notes': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  'subtotal': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### you have the option to create custom validation

```
this.profile = this.fb.group({
              title : [null, [Validators.required]],
              nickName : [null, []],
              firstName: [null, [Validators.required]],
              lastName : [null, []]
        })
```

Comment: and in the constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

Comment: Doesn't work. I write like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110849/how-to-send-to-ws-the-value-of-an-input-which-is-unmodified-formcontrolname

Comment: It is already a downvoted and not used the best practices even you check the documentation they are following this pattern only as it provides more customization to your architecture